# oAuth2 returns 400 when including javascript files in header or body

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0

I am creating an implicit login service for an HTML5 mobile app.

I followed the examples given for the implicit pages.

When in the form supplied by the server I include the following 2 files, I get error 400 bad request.

{"ErrorCode" : "invalid_request", "Error" :"The request is missing a required parameter : client_id"}

The crazy thing is that when I include one of the above files I do not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was jQuery Mobile.
It seems to be cutting off form parameters to the after login php script.

I use jqm for my HTML5 mobile app.
But for the server implicit login I use bootstrap to avoid this problem.